# Convert The Difference Between StartDate and EndDate Into Hours, Minutes And Seconds

Tags: t-sql

Suppose I have a StartDate and an EndDate, how do I format or convert the difference into hh:mm:ss?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(10), Dateadd(Second, DATEDIFF(Second,StartDate,EndDate),0), 108)
```

For Example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime

SET @StartDate = '2014-06-08 07:18:12.893'
SET @EndDate = '2014-06-09 05:58:40.893'

SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(10), Dateadd(Second, DATEDIFF(Second,@StartDate,@EndDate),0), 108)
```

**Output:**

```
+---------+
|  Time   |
+---------+
|22:40:28 |
+---------+
```

---

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18450)**